# LDA for Exim+SA

Tags: exim, procmail, maildir

I have a mail server running Exim and Dovecot, backed by MySQL for virtual users. Spamassassin is configured and seems to be working reasonably, but sending flagged spams to a "spam" dir for the recipient is not configured. We are using the maildir format for storage.

How would I go about processing where mails are to be delivered to? I would have thought procmail could do this, but I don't see any decent configs for this particular setup.

In short:
 - Exim
 - Spamassassin
 - Virtual Users, root of each user = /home/mail/$domain/$local_part
 - Want to deliver spams to /home/mail/$domain/$local_part/spam/ for example

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that should work ok. I've based it off the standard "local delivery" router/transports, but added in conditions on the X-Spam-Flag header, which I'm setting earlier in the relevant ACL. If you don't know how to do that, let me know and I'll amend the answer.

I do something similar, but at a domain level, and my setup probably won't work too well for you.

First of all, you need a router. Routers are processed in order, so put this somewhere suitable - generally before you catch normal mail, because that will take precedence.

```
spamcheck:
 debug_print = "R: spamcheck for $local_part@$domain"
 driver = accept
 check_local_user
 user = mail
 condition = "${if def:h_X-Spam-Flag: {yes}{no}}"
 transport = local_spam_delivery
```

Now you need a local_spam_delivery transport, so put this anywhere in your transports section:

```
local_spam_delivery:
 debug_print = "T: local_spam_delivery for $local_part@$domain"
 driver = appendfile
 directory = /home/mail/$domain/$local_part/spam/
 maildir_format
 delivery_date_add
 envelope_to_add
 return_path_add
```

If you don't want it as a maildir, remove the maildir_format command. You may have to tweak the rules a bit, especially regarding user and group settings etc.

If there is something missing in my above example, I notice there's a similar example documented [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/exim-users@exim.org/msg03972.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this easily with a couple of routers. Alternatively, you can use an exim filter file to do it.

I have the following in my ~/.forward, but you could easily use something similar for your global filter file.

```
if $spam_score_int is not "" then
   if $spam_score_int is above 49 then save $home/Maildir/.SPAM/ finish endif
endif
```

Using your path should work. Just replace replace it in the example and don't forget the trailing slash or you may end up delivering to mbox format.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following to send spam to a maildir called "Junk" for each domain.

```
mysql_delivery:
   driver = appendfile
   maildir_format
   directory = "${if and { {def:h_X-Spam-Flag:} {eq {$h_X-Spam-Flag}{YES}}} {/home/mail/${domain}/${local_part}/.Junk}{/home/mail/${domain}/${local_part}} }"
```

I guess I was thinking about it too hard when I originally posted the question. The above appears to be working quite well. I will accept Daniel's answer though.

Comment: Why, because he wrote the most?